# Can I remove a specific turret when playing as Symmetra?

Tags: overwatch

Symmetra can place lots of small turrets, but only 6 at once. I'd like to be able to remove a specific turret, but I'm not sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Once you've hit the limit, placing a new one removes the oldest one, but there is no way to remove a specific turret, unless you manage to lure over an enemy team member to destroy it.